# Penalty method problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

Penalty method problem

Consider the following problem

\begin{align}
   \text{min}&\quad \frac12(x^2_1+x^2_2)&& \\
   \text{s.t}& \quad  x_1+x_2=2&& 
\end{align}

a)Apply non-differentiable penalty $(i.e., f(x)+\rho \Vert h(x) \Vert _1
)$ and verify if there is a finite penalty parameter $(\rho>0)$ such that solution of the penalized problem coincides with the solution of the original problem.

observation: $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac12(x^2_1+x^2_2)$,  $\quad h(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2 -2$ ,$\quad \Vert x \Vert _1=\sum_{i=1}^n \vert x_i \vert $

the solution of the original problem is (1,1)

Comment: I downvotes because the question "help me" is too broad. Show more effort and specify where you encounter problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we don't need the soccer here because by C-S $$\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)=\frac{1}{4}(1^2+1^2)(x_1^2+x_2^2)\geq\frac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2=1.$$
The equality occurs for $x_1=x_2=1$, which says that $1$ is a minimal value.